# for (var i in yourObjects) { ... } and .hasOwnProperty() ... discussion

Tags: javascript

```
var yourObjects = [ 

{ object: {obj1:"aa"}, direction: 'top' },
{ object: "obj2", direction: 'left' }, 
{ object: "obj3", direction: 'bottom' }

]; 

for (var i in yourObjects) { alert(i); }
```

There was a long discussion about that. 
Using `for in` to iterate an Object returns all properties and methods of the Object, so normally [.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method should be used. But when we iterate an array, in fact `for in` iterates the indexes of the array (or keys if it is an associative array). I tried it in all browsers I have. But when tried in jsfiddle  ... it wasn't the same ... returned all methods which an array have.

So my questin is: Is it safe to use `for in` to iterate an array?

Try this code in your browser and in jsfiddle, and tell me what do you think.

Comment: An associative array in javascript is an `Object`.

Comment: Actually `isArray()` returns true for Assoc. Array ...and false for an Object

Comment: Javascript has interesting 'opinions' about types, equalities and other stuff. :) [see here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182416/A-Collection-of-JavaScript-Gotchas)

Comment: You should check Perl opinions for variables, equations and other stuff :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's more than one reason to not use `for-in` on an Array.

Remeber that in JavaScript, an Array is just a type of Object, so doing `for-in` on an Array is no different from doing `for-in` on a plain Object.

In your jsFiddle, you probably had a library selected on the left that augmented `Array.prototype`, which would be where those methods came from.

But there's another reason. A `for-in` makes no guarantee of the order in which the properties are enumerated. Because there's no constraint, it could enumerate your indices out of order, and be totally in conformance with ECMAScript.

Also, there are Array-like collections, like NodeLists that also should not use `for-in` because they  contain default properties that can be enumerated in addition to the DOM elements.

The simple fact is that in JavaScript, `for-in` is not a proper tool for index-based enumeration.

---

With respect to objects, you should only need to use `hasOwnProperty` when there's a specific need for it.

Some people suggest that it must be used on all objects. That's an extremely paranoid mentality. That method is a guard that should be used in those *narrow* situations where it makes sense.

Most of the time it doesn't make any sense to use it, as long as you conform to good programming practices. This includes not placing enumerable properties on `Object.prototype`. It's a just simple and reasonable requirement to make of a programming environment.

The time where it *does* make sense is when you're enumerating an object created from a custom constructor that has its `.prototype` extended with enumerable properties. In that case, it's an appropriate guard to use.

To use it on plain objects is massive overkill, when a more rational approach would be to have simple requirements that your environment not alter `Object.prototype`.